# Creating animation for web-based game

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

Currently i am learning about node js and angular js, also about socket.io and express.js. I am trying to create a poker multiplayer game like texas hold em. but after browsed the internet for quite amount of time, i cant figure out how to create animation for my project, such as flipping the card, distributing the card. Is there any tool that I can use to create the animation?? I am new to this environment, and keep learning day by day.

But First, i am so sorry if this is out of topic or whatsoever. Because I am totally have no idea how to proceed to the next step in my project.

Any help given is much appreciated.

Comment: I suggest you use a graphic engine for this, something like [ImpactJS](http://impactjs.com/). It is based on JavaScript and the Canvas element, and it should integrate in your project easily.

Comment: @niandrei http://impactjs.com/ is not free :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you are new to client side development. I can advice you to learn some books about JavaScript and then use some canvas based libraries which will help you to build your card game.

There are many canvas libraries for you:

- http://phaser.io/
- http://createjs.com/
- https://playcanvas.com/
- https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js

and others

If you are new to JavaScript I can recommend you: [Object-Oriented JavaScript - Second Edition](https://www.packtpub.com/web-development/object-oriented-javascript-second-edition) book. This book is for anyone who is starting to learn JavaScript or who knows JavaScript but isn't very good at the object-oriented part of it.

Comment: sir i really appreciate your kindness. You really helped me a lot as a new-comer. thanks :)

Comment: Thank you too,  I am glad to help you :)